# What is the plain JavaScript equivalent of this jquery.ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

How can I re-write the below jQuery.Ajax call without using jQuery but using only plain JavaScript?

Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(request),
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Submitted succesfully!");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert('Error Occured' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to find out exactly what the ajax function in jQuery does, open the jquery source and have a look at the ajax function, here's a link to the source.

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
```

If you want to do this without jQuery, you have to create an Xml Http Request

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

This is basically what AJAX is (asynchronous javascript and xml).

Here's an example:

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

else{ // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

This will create an xmlhttp object, and send it with GET to a specified url, in this case a txt-file, and ask for it's content. The data is returned in xml, and we save it into `xmlDoc`. Now you're free to use the data how ever you want.

I hope this helps!

Comment: True, but I'm not really sure that's the information the OP is looking for, although perhaps they can clarify.

Comment: It sounds as though they just want to perform the AJAX call, they aren't interested in all of the extra handling of options, etc that jQuery is going to do internally.

Comment: Well, jQuery does ALOT, it's not like $.ajax() will do one line of code, so it's really not a simple question, the ONLY way to figure it out is to look in the source.

Comment: Well if he's interested in creating a new lib for ajax, go ahead, but to clarify then. Ajax is an XmlHttpRequest, http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: @StefanKonno Agreed--what I'm saying is that I think they're looking for the old-school, non-library way of making a JSON Ajax request. (As opposed to "replacing every piece of jQuery functionality". I could be wrong, which is why I was hoping the OP would explain what precisely they're looking for.)

Comment: @DaveNewton yes I know what you mean, and you're right. The phrasing of the question confuses me though since he's asking for an equivalent. But yeah, let's hope he clarifies his intentions. I'll add a link to my answer on how he does this. Thank you for your input. :)

Comment: Why does this plain javascript ajax call look so synchronous?